# Add Tag with multiple values in influxline/influxdb

Tags: influxdb, influxql, influx-line-protocol

Is it possible to send multiple values in a single tag in influxdb using the influxdb line protocol?

Something like this

```
application-metric, application=test-app,API=get,put cpu=15 1465839830100400200
```

Essentially measurement and timestamp are the same but different tags of the same key.
InfluxDB: 1.8

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get what you want, so I just answering blind folded:

Influx 1.8 takes as line protocol one measurement and one (optional) timestamp. Then you can add as many tags and fields (=values) as you like.

Syntax is:

```
measurement(,tag_set) field_set (timestamp)
```

where as `tag_set` is `tag_key=tag_value` and `field_set` is `field_key=field_value` each of them comma-separated if >1
therefore it works without tags and 3 fields (=values):

```
myMeasurement temperature1=10,temperature2=20,status="all good" 1556813561098000000
```

with tags "sensor" and "location" and 3 fields:

```
myMeasurement,sensor=627,location=Narnia temperature1=10,temperature2=20,status="all good" 1556813561098000000
```

That's possible in one line. But you can not send two different tag-value-couples in one line. And you can't write two different points with same `field_set` but different `tag_value` for the same `tag_key` in the same line (afaik).

If you need several different "values" in one tag you could send it somehow separated by whatever and regex for it later:

```
myMeasurement,location=Narnia;South-West;Valley4 temperature1=10 1556813561098000000
SELECT * FROM myMeasurement WHERE location=~ /.*;South-West;.*/
```